# Structure printf stops the program from working

Tags: c

I created the following code, it compiles but it doesen't run properly. It shows some imput witch is correct, but after that, instead of printing according to the line `printf(prod[0].dr[0]);` it enters an "not responding" state. If you instead write `printf(prod[0].dr);` it works perfectly. I need to be able to print each character individualy (so I need something like `printf(prod[0].dr[0]);` that works)

If the question is to broad, please comment and I will try to specify every detail.

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *f, *g;

struct productie
{
    char st, dr[20];
    int realizabil;
}prod[30];

int citire(FILE *f){
char sir[100];
int i=0,j;
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        fgets(sir,100,f);
        prod[i].st=sir[0];
        for(j=3;j<strlen(sir);j++)
            prod[i].dr[j-3]=sir[j];
        i++;
    }
return i;
}

int exista(char sir[],char c)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(sir);i++)
    {
        if(c==sir[i])
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void neterminale(struct productie p[],int n, char N[])
{
    int k=0;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(isupper(p[i].st) && !exista(N,p[i].st))
            N[k++]=p[i].st;
        for(j=0;j<strlen(p[i].dr);j++)
            if(isupper(p[i].dr[j]) && !exista(N,p[i].dr[j]))
                N[k++]=p[i].dr[j];
    }
    N[k]='\0';
}

void terminale(struct productie p[],int n, char T[],char N[]) 
{
    int k=0;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(!exista(N,p[i].st) && !exista(T,p[i].st)&& p[i].st!='$')
            T[k++]=p[i].st;
        for(j=0;j<strlen(p[i].dr);j++)
            if(!exista(N,p[i].dr[j]) && !exista(T,p[i].dr[j]) && p[i].dr[j]!='$')
                T[k++] = p[i].dr[j];
    }
    T[k]='\0';
}


void afisare(FILE *g,int n){
int i;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        fprintf(g,"%c -> %s",prod[i].st, prod[i].dr);

}

int main(){
char N[30];
char T[30];
int i,j,n;

f=fopen("in.txt","r");
n=citire(f);
neterminale(prod,n,N);
printf("\nNeterminalele sunt:{");
for(i=0;i<strlen(N);i++)
    printf("%c ",N[i]);
printf("}");
terminale(prod,n,T,N);
printf("\nTerminalele sunt:{");
for(i=0;i<strlen(T);i++)
    {
        printf(" %c ",T[i]);
    }
printf("}");

printf(prod[0].dr[0]);                   //AT THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM

g=fopen("out.txt","w");
afisare(g,n);


fclose(f);
fclose(g);
return 0;
}
```

The in.txt :

S->aS

S->a

S->$

S->AB

A->b

B->c

Comment: `prod[0].dr[0]` is of type `char`. Printf expects its first argument to be a format string of type `char *`. Try `printf("%c", prod[0].dr[0])`. You compiler should have warned you about this--make sure all those warnings are turned on.

Comment: more likely OP just ignored the warnings. my 10c say that -Werror should be the default

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` ) .  To start, the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>`  to expose the `strlen()` function

Comment: @pm100,  I agree,  So many postings on stackoverflow where the OP says the code cleanly compiles, but the reality is it doesn't even come close to cleanly compiling.  This question being an excellent example.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror()` so your text and the text from the system that indicates why the system thinks the operation failed are output to `stderr`.

Comment: function parameter names and variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  names like: `T`, `f`, `n`, `g`, `N`, `p[]`, etc are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <ctype.h>` to expose items like: `isupper()`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code. indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. 2) separate code blocks ( for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default ) via a single blank line. 3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent) 4) insert appropriate horizontal spacing: inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators. 5) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `for(i=0;i<strlen(T);i++)`  invoking the function: `strlen()` on every iteration of the loop is 'expensive' in CPU cycles.  Suggest using something similar to: `for( i=0 ; T[i]; i++ )`  which accomplishes the same thing with out any function calls

Comment: good programming practice is to limit the 'scope' of variables as much as possible. For instance, in function: `terminale()`, the variables 'i' and 'j' are visible through the whole scope of the function.  They should be limited to the `for()` loops they are actually used in.  Suggest remove the statement: `int i,j;` and use `for()` statements like: `for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a string directly, you need to provide a pointer to the first character, not the first character itself:

```
printf(&(prod[0].dr[0]));
```

or

```
printf(prod[0].dr);
```

But you can't limit this to a single char (there is no nprintf function).

Comment: actually, the first parameter to `printf()` is expected to be a "format string", not the data.  so the statement should be: `printf( "%c", prod[0].dr[0] );` to print one character